# Rails: retrieve values from a table without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails is there any way to retrieve values from a table which does not have any model? I have created a table item_types with the fields name and item_id in which item_id is the primary key of another table items. Each item in items table can have 3 or 4 item_types. Here I want to display the corresponding item_types of an item with a particular item_id. We just have the item_id of a specific item in a variable @item.id
I have tried forming an sql query, but I don't know how to implement it without a model. Also I am not sure whether the 'item_id = @item.id' part of the query below is correct.

```
select * from item_types where item_id = @item.id
```

Comment: But why you are not create the model for that, is there any reason for that ?

Comment: @Bharatsoni No, I am sorry if that was a stupid question. After creating the table I was thinking of retrieving values from that table. If we can't do that without a model can you please suggest me how to create the model for an existing table?

Comment: (rails g model item_type --skip-migration) that command will create a model for you, here skip migration will not generate the migration file because you have already a table in your data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is a `join_model`, which can either be used with a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), or [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship

I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but I would highly recommend employing a `has_many :through` association in your independent models:

```
#app/models/type.rb
Class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_types
    has_many :items, through: :item_types
end

#app/models/item.rb
Class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :item_types
    has_many :types, through: :item_types
end

#app/models/item_type.rb
Class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :type
end
```

This will allow you to call the `join_model` through your other models, like this:

```
@item = Item.find(params[:id])
@item.item_types #-> calls SQL "select * from item_types where item_id = @item.id"
```

This is the correct Rails way to do this. `HABTM` doesn't use a model; `HMT` does.  You should generate a model using `@Bharat Soni's` comment & access it with my snippet

Comment: But my doubt is why do we need another model 'type.rb'? After creating the model item_type.rb we just need to mention `belongs_to :item` in models/item_type.rb and `has_many :item_types` in models/item.rb right? Then I used the statement `@item_types = ItemType.where("item_id = #{@item.id}").order("name ASC")`. And that worked for me.

Comment: Well the answer to your question is in another question -> where are `types` stored?